# vb .net how I can Re Arrange Data

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a text file contains data in the format

100;10:24

100;11:34

200;9:40

200;12:45

how I can convert the data after reading to the format

100 10:24 11:34

200 9:40 12:45

as result I want to combine all line starts with 100 in single line 100 is a key and starts with 200 in line so the first column is a key

Comment: So you want to overwrite the whole file?

Comment: or in a new file the important is to have the new shape of data

Answer (score 3):

You can use `File.ReadLines` to read the lines, LINQ's `Enumerable.GroupBy` to group by the first field and `File.WriteAllLines` to overwrite the file (or to write to a different file):

```
Dim newLines = From line In File.ReadLines("Path")
               Let fields = line.Split({";"c}, StringSplitOptions.None)
               Where fields.Length >= 2
               Group fields By FirstCol = fields(0).Trim() Into FirstColGroup = Group
               Select String.Format("{0} {1}",
                   FirstCol,
                   String.Join(" ", From fields In FirstColGroup Select fields(1)))

File.WriteAllLines("Path", newLines.ToList())
```

[`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) concatenates all second fields(`arr(1)`) using space as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

create a dictionary with the first part of a line as key and a list of String, or a corresponding data type, as value. Put the second part of you line into the list.
Then, as you walk through your File data, parse it into the structure, after that use it to overwrite you old file or do what ever you want with your data.